# JQuery : .one() not work in my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code for JQuery:-

```
$('.ro-news-n img').addClass('no-display');
$('.ro-news-n img').one('inview', function() {
$(this).addClass('appear');
});
```

This code for hide any image in class `.ro-news-n` and show it when scroll page down.

Its add class no-display for `<img>` attribute and when scroll its add appear class to show it.

The problem is when open site its add class no-display to `<img>` attribute. but when scroll its not add appear class to it.

why

Comment: what is error in console??

Comment: `inview` is not a standard Javascript event. Have you loaded the plugin to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).removeClass('no-display').addClass('appear');
```

Comment: its same thing not remove 'no-display'

Comment: If that's not working, it will be something related with the event. Try this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3535028/2979648](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3535028/2979648)

Comment: how can i put it in my code ??| and i see some site its work in it like this site : `http://theme-sphere.com/smart-mag/`

Comment: 1. go to [https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear), download "jquery.appear.js" and put it in your code: `<script src='jquery.appear.js'></script>`. 2. Use the "appear" event: `$('.ro-news-n img').appear(function() { $(this).removeClass('no-display').addClass('appear');});`
3. Enjoy

Comment: sorry its still no-display

Comment: Show us more code, show your styles. How is you img tag?